Updating SSL Certification on Always-On Availability group
We have Always-On Availability group SSL certificate that is going to expire for the next 2 months. I understand that renewing the certificate just simply need to go to mmc and click renew.
But need advise what is the sequence of the renewal, should I do it on Secondary replica first then restart the sql service. Or I can do directly on primay replica without failover. Thank you Sir!

You should renew the certificate on the Secondary Replica first. After renewing the certificate on a secondary replica, you should restart the SQL Server service on that replica to apply the new certificate. After that proceed to renew the certificate on the primary replica and restart the SQL Server on primary replica. Check the synchronization status, connectivity, and that no databases are in a suspended state. Also check nodes status(primary-secondary).
